# Best way to transform labeled rows into columns in R

Tags: r

I have the next set of data:

```
     
V1          V2
label1      a
label2      b
label3      c
label1      d
label2      e
label3      f
.
.
label1      x
label2      y
label3      z
```

Then, I want to transform into this

```
     
label1      label2      label3
a           b           c
d           e           f
...
x           y           z
```

Whic is the best way to do it in R? Are there any built-in functions for this specific task?

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Well, the data I have to arrange is a little more complicated than that. But, for the transposing part, I used for loops, counters and if conditionals. The specific code is not relevant. I just wanted to know what was the best way to transpose the shown data, and as 'akrun' pointed out, the best way is with unstack() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `unstack`

```
unstack(df1, V2~V1)
#    label1 label2 label3
#1      a      b      c
#2      d      e      f
#3      x      y      z
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("label1", "label2", 
"label3", "label1", 
"label2", "label3", "label1", "label2", "label3"), 
V2 = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "x", "y", "z")), 
.Names = c("V1", "V2"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: Thanks akrun! That is what I am looking for.